# Problemas para instalar el compilador de C++ en Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, codeblocks, gcc, compilador

Recientemente por la universidad tuve que instalar un virtual box con **Ubuntu 18.04 lts** para poder programar en C++.

Ya instale *code::blocks* pero estoy teniendo problemas con el compilador gcc.

Utilizo el comando:

`sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Y devuelve:

> No se pudieron instalar algunos paquetes. Esto puede significar que usted pidió una situación imposible o, si está usando la distribución inestable, que algunos paquetes necesarios aún no se han creado o se han sacado de «Incoming». La siguiente información puede ayudar a resolver la situación:
>
> Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
> build-essential:
>
> Depende: libc6-dev pero no va a instalarse o libc-dev
>
> Depende: gcc (>= 4:7.2) pero no va a instalarse
>
> Depende: g++ (>= 4:7.2) pero no va a instalarse
>
> Depende: dpkg-dev (>= 1.17.11) pero no va a instalarse
>
> E: No se pudieron corregir los problemas, usted ha retenido paquetes rotos.

Si intento instalar directo gcc:

`sudo apt-get install gcc`

Cambian las "dependencias incumplidas" a solo una y una recomendación:

> Depende: gcc-7 (>= 7.3.0-12~) pero no va a instalarse
>
> Recomienda: libc6-dev pero no va a instalarse o libc-dev

¿Alguien me podría dar una mano o algún comando para probar?

Comment: Hola. ¿Hiciste un `apt-get update` antes de intentar la instalación?

Comment: Hola Adrián. Antes de realizar cualquier instalación utilizo el apt-get update. No se si conoces otro comando o configuración que pueda utilizar para reparar los "paquetes rotos"

Comment: Se podría hacer un workarround, podrías instalar paquetes usando `aptitude`. Pero lo mejor es resolver las dependencias rotas. Intenta resolver las dependencias que indican aquí: https://ubunlog.com/resolver-las-dependencias-de-paquetes/

Comment: Hola, Paso a explicar para guardar la solución.
Fue un caso curioso, tu link no funciono, pero me sirvió mucho que nombraste aptitude. Lo instale (`apt install aptitude`) y luego utilice `aptitude install build-essential`. Mostró como 17 paquetes que estaban teniendo problemas, la opción por defecto los deja tal cual, pero puedes desactualizarlos.
Al desactualizarlos quedaron en la version que precisaba build-essential, por lo que se instaló el compilador gcc y g++ sin inconvenientes.
Ya realice la prueba por code::blocks y no se necesitó hacer nada mas.
Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: @Drazian por favor, pon la respuesta en el campo de respuesta para que otros sepan que hacer. Así los que encuentren útil tu solución podran votarla positiva y tú podrás marcarla como la respuesta aceptada

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCIÓN:

Se instala aptitude:

> sudo apt install aptitude

Luego se fuerza la instalación por aptitude:

> sudo aptitude install build-essencial

Por defecto aptitude me daba la opción de dejar todo sin cambios, pero rechacé su solución (pulsando "n"), y la siguiente solución que propuso fue desactualizar las librerias con problemas.

Al desactualizarlas quedaron en la versión exacta que pedía build-essencial, logrando instalar asi los compiladores gcc (compilador de C) y g++ (compilador de C++)